# Some asstes not serving to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline, asset-sync

My asstes are served to S3 using asset_sync (1.0.0) 
and all work almost fine, just the assets loaded from `css`, like `background-image:url..`
and all the `javascript` files like `<script src="/assets/public/js_validation.js"></script>` dose not get pushed to `s3`
those assets points to `https://xxx.herokuapp.com/assets/sub-dir/..` but they do get precompiled.  Also some of those assets do get push to `s3` but with premitions issues. 
To recap, I think the problem is that all the assets outside the `css/js` manifest is been ignored when pushing to `s3`.. ??

many thanks.

**EDIT**

working assets in production :
`some_asset.xxxxxxxxxxxx.png`

Not working assets in production : `some_asset.png` ( assets outside manifest files )

in development all seems to work....

Any ideas ?

Update :

**view**

`<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/js_standalone/validation.js" %>`

=> `<script src="//d3j9rtukkaxslew.cloudfront.net/assets/js_standalone/homepage.js"></script>`

**production.rb**

```
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.enabled = true
  config.assets.precompile += ['js_standalone/*.js']
  config.assets.compile = true
```

On S3 I you the fingerprint added at the end of the file

`homepage-ee97ca738affc4938c92445069f21cd2.js`

but not in the production I get this error message `[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) (validation.js, line 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

I was using  `<%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/js_standalone/validation.js" %>` in my template.

I've removed the `assets` from the path on now it works...

`<%= javascript_include_tag "js_standalone/validation" %>`